# SELECT sums per subcat FROM subquery AS columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

Given 3 tables (Contracts,Services,Contracts_Services)

A Contract as multiple Services organized in 4 types (for now, more will come).

What I need is to get the SUM() of all prices GROUP BY service_type FOR EACH Contract, one row per Contract.

contracts.id,'total_service_type_1','total_service_type_2','total_service_type_3','total_service_type_4'

### Contracts

- id

### Services

- id
- servicetype_id

### Contracts_Services

- contract_id
- service_id
- price

Here is what I got so far

```
SELECT c.id,s.servicetype_id,sum(cs.price)as total
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id = c.address_id
LEFT JOIN contracts_services cs ON cs.contract_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN services s ON s.id = cs.service_id
WHERE s.servicetype_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.id,s.servicetype_id
ORDER BY c.id
```

How can I turn these query results into columns for a single Contract row?

Comment: use the AND in where and apply filter on table C

Comment: `WHERE s.servicetype_id IS NOT NULL` will convert all LEFT JOINs to  INNER JOINs. The table `addresses` is not really used in the query - so it's not clear why you join it. "GROUP BY service_type FOR EACH Contract, one row per Contract" is not clear. Do you want one row per contract or one row per combination of contract and service type?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel What I need is 1 row per Contract

    contracts.id,'total_service_type_1','total_service_type_2','total_service_type_3','total_service_type_4'

Even if a Contract doesn't have a Service with type_(n).

I need to know the total for each service_type for eahc Contract.

Comment: Seems you are looking for "pivoting". I would (usually) solve that in application language. But this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have dynamic columns in MySQL (or any SQL-flavor as far as I know). So you can only achieve this by adding every service-type as a new `join` to your query. I've added two service-types in below example for brevity, for extra service-types just add more `LEFT JOIN`.

With that last said: there is your pain. This solution is absolutely not flexible. With every new service-type you add, you have to edit your query again. You should really look for a solution within your programming language. Thus when you are calling `MySQL` from `PHP`, use your query you already had and was working nearly great, and use `PHP` to rewrite your array (dynamically) so you get the desired output (replace `PHP` by the programming language you are using).

```
SELECT 
  c.id AS contractId, 
  SUM(cs1.price) AS service1Total,
  SUM(cs2.price) AS service2Total
FROM contracts c
JOIN services s
LEFT JOIN contracts_services cs1 ON 
  cs1.contract_id = c.id 
  AND cs1.service_id = s.id
  AND s.servicetype_id = 1
LEFT JOIN contracts_services cs2 ON 
  cs2.contract_id = c.id 
  AND cs2.service_id = s.id
  AND s.servicetype_id = 2
GROUP BY c.id
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f9a9c/2/0

Note: You can replace `SUM(cs1.price)` with `IFNULL(SUM(cs1.price), 0)` if you prefer `0` over `NULL`.

Edit: Alternative query, after reading Paul Spiegel's comment (about pivot tables), with less joins and thus more likely to be friendly to your database-server. However with the same drawback as above query: you have to edit it every time you add a new service-type.

```
SELECT 
  c.id AS contractId, 
  SUM(IF(s.servicetype_id = 1, cs.price, 0)) AS service1Total,
  SUM(IF(s.servicetype_id = 2, cs.price, 0)) AS service2Total
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN contracts_services cs ON cs.contract_id = c.id 
LEFT JOIN services s ON cs.service_id = s.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try generating the JOIN parts in App code (PHP), and run the final query

Comment: Ideally (if I were you) I would use the original query in your question and handle the translation from 'multiple rows in query output' to 'a single row in my HTML-table' within PHP - instead of using PHP to build a (large) SQL-query. The first method shouldn't be that hard to program

Comment: You are right. The alternative query works much faster on my 100K+ Contracts table